# Easy Riemann integral question

Tags: real-analysis

Find all functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and $\int_0^xf(t)dt$ = $\int_x^1f(t)dt$ for every $x\in (0,1)$.

Attempt: Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, there exists a primitive $F$ on $[0,1]$ such that
$f=F'$. So $F(x)-F(0) = F(1)-F(x)$ and so $F(x) = 1/2(F(0) + F(1))$. Then $f(x) = \int_0^1[1/2(F(0)+F(1))]dt$ = $1/2(F(0)+F(1))$. I'm pretty sure this is way off, so could anyone help?

Comment: You are way off, unless $F(0)=0=F(1)$...

Comment: That's what I thought. Initially, I couldn't visualize any functions other than the zero function satisfying this.

Comment: You showed that $F(x)$ is a constant so you are pretty much done. Your last equation is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trust your instincts! Here's a sketch, since it's homework: suppose $f$ were nonzero, say WLOG positive (replace $f$ with $-f$, it'll have the same property) at some point $x$.

Near $x$, $f$ is positive. So, $\int_0^{x - \epsilon}f$ will be smaller than $\int_0^xf$, and $\int_{x - \epsilon}^1f$ will be bigger than $\int_x^1f$...

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)\gt0$ the left side integral is increasing. If $f(x)\lt0$ the left side integral is decreasing. This is because
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=f(x)\tag{1}
$$
If $f(x)\gt0$ the right side integral is decreasing. If $f(x)\lt0$ the right side integral is increasing. This is because
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_x^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=-f(x)\tag{2}
$$
Differentiating your equation says that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal.